# Show that if $p$ is a prime of the form $p=4n+1$, then we can solve $x^2\equiv -1\mod p$(with $x$ an integer).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

> Show that if $p$ is a prime of the form $p=4n+1$, then we can solve $x^2\equiv -1\mod p$(with $x$ an integer).

My attempt:If $p$ is a prime, then $U_p=${$[x]|1\leq x<p$} is cyclic.

Comment: And what size does the group $U_p$ have?

Comment: Hey, this is the whole reason why they gave you the other exercise http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778152/using-wilsons-theorem-show-that-if-p-is-prime-of-the-form-p-4n1-and-if-y/778153#778153

Comment: @AndreasCaranti And at the end of the Problem 42: "This gives another proof of the result in Problem 41." So I think there may be another way to do.

Comment: Of course there is, I will write it in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), whose proof is relatively elementary, says that the non-zero element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a quadratic residue iff
$$
a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}  = 1.
$$
In this case $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is even, so that
$$
(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}  = 1.
$$

Comment: This is a very elegant simple proof, thanks you. I also think it can be proved using the fact that $U_p$ is cyclic, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, cyclic of order $4n$, with a generating element, say $a$. Then we have $(-1)=a^k$ for some $k$ in $\{0,..,4n-1\}$, but as $(-1)^2=1$ we must have $k=2n$. Then, $(-1)=(a^n)^2$.

Comment: @Berci This is a clever way to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an alternative proof that goes back to Dirichlet. Note that for every $x$ in the interval $1$ to $p=1$, there is a unique $y$ in that interval such that $xy\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.  Let $p=4k+1$. Suppose that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution. We will show that leads to a contradiction.

If $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution, then the unique $y$ described above is not congruent to $x$ modulo $p$.

Thus the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$ can be divided into "couples" with product congruent to $-1$ modulo $p$. It follows that $(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^{2k}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.  This contradicts Wilson's Theorem.

Comment: Don't know how to understand that there is a unique y such that $xy\equiv 1\mod p$, but I must say that this answer is quite useful too!

Comment: We have $xy\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ if and only if  $y\equiv-(x^{-1})\pmod{p}$, where $x^{-1}$ is the modular inverse of $x$.